# "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token;

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

Есть контроллер

```
@RestController
public class HandlerRequest {
    @GetMapping("/schedule")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Meeting> build(@RequestBody List<BookingRequest> bookingRequests, @RequestBody String workTime) {
        return Builder.build(bookingRequests, workTime);
    }
```

Отправляю json через Postman

```
{
    "bookingRequests" : [] , 
    "workTime" : "1130 1730"
}
```

В ответ приходит

```
{
    "timestamp": 1507146731039,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",
    "path": "/schedule"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тело у `Post` запроса может быть только одно. Вам надо сделать класс-обёртку для всех параметров и в теле метода вытаскивать из неё параметры. Типа как-то [так](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12893566/3212712):

```
@GetMapping("/schedule")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<Meeting> build(@RequestBody Data data) {
    return Builder.build(data.bookingRequests, data.workTime);
}

public static class Data {
    public List<BookingRequest> bookingRequests;
    public String workTime;
}
```

А в ошибке у вас сказано, что при попытке распарсить тело как список объектов по факту оказался объект, что и привело к падению.

Comment: Также можно не создавая класс обёртку определить тип тела запроса как `Map<String, String>` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33749674/3212712

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое

Comment: Вообще , думал что Spring очень мощная штука , странно , что так нельзя сделать

Comment: @flagmen, я не специалист и никогда со спрингом дел не имел, но, как я понимаю, это ограничение стандарта `Http` запросов - параметров может быть много, а вот тело может быть только одно. С другой стороны, вроде, можно как-то тело из нескольких частей передавать - через другую аннотацию - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753785/3212712